# White noise not strongly stationary

Tags: probability, stationary-processes, noise

Let $t=0,1,2,3,...$  a discrete time index. Consider the following process

[image]

where $\gamma(t_1,t_2)$ indicates the autocovariance function. I want to prove that the process (although being autocovariance stationary) is not strongly stationary, i.e. the distribution of the variables $Z_t$ depends on time. Any help?

Comment: $t$ should start from $1$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if two random variables have all their moments to be the same, it does not follow that they have the same distributions. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84219/whether-distributions-with-the-same-moments-are-identical) for some counterexamples.

You could however check whether the charactristic function of $Z_t$ is independent of $t$ in your case. For $Z_t$ we have $$\phi_{Z_t}(\theta)=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos tx}{2\pi}\exp(i\theta x)dx=\frac{i\theta \left(1-e^{2i\pi\theta}\right)}{2\pi\left(\theta^2-t^2\right)},$$
which is a function of $t$. Therefore the distribution of $Z_t$ depends on $t$. You could also look the distributions of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ which are rather simple, but tedious to derive, and see that they are different.